# Local service (The server has rejected the client credentials.)

Tags: wcf

I have a simple setup, a WPF application running on the machine and a WCF service hosted within a Windows Service on the same machine (always on the same machine). When i debug on one computer i can easily access the local WCF Service. When i run it on another machine i get an error:

***"The server has rejected the client credentials."***

Some of my observations are, that at my local machine i have no domain/network. Its my home machine. When at a customers site, it will not run, and gives the above error. Anyone got any ideas on why this is different on these computers?

/Brian

**Edit:**

Contract:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://www.greenweb.dk/motiondetection")]
    public interface IMotionDetection
    {
        [OperationContract]
        bool GetMotionDetected();
    }
```

App.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings />
    <client />
    <services>
      <service name="GreenWebPlayerMotionDetectionService.MotionDetected" behaviorConfiguration="MotionDetectionBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.pipe://localhost/GreenWebMotionDetectionService/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" contract="GreenWebPlayerMotionDetectionService.IMotionDetection" binding="netNamedPipeBinding"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexNamedPipeBinding"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MotionDetectionBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel> 
</configuration>
```

**Edit 2**
Security will not be a problem, no security is neeed, the computer on which it runs is already isolated from everything else.

**EDIt 3**
Have set `<security mode="None"></security>` on both the client and the server, now im getting this error: "There was an error reading from the pipe: Unrecognized error 109 (0x6)"

I can't figure out whether this is a step in the right direction

Comment: You don't give us much to go on..... what bindings are you using? What security settings? What does the service look like?

Comment: Please see edit details for more info

Comment: Brian, did you ever get this working? I am having the exact same problem now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be the security. Instead of None i set the client and server to be "EncryptAndSign". This however wasnt enough when the host was a windows service. I abandoned the windows service approach and hosted it in a windows application instead - then it worked immediately...go figure!

Comment: In my experience, the host of the WCF service will affect its security settings. If you change your host from Console application to WPF application, sometimes you need to modify WCF service's security settings.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the

> netNamedPipeBinding

.This binding is used to communicate inside a machine. Please check the link.Its for on-machine .

If you want to communicate between 2 machine which uses .net select net.tcp .If you want to communicate between .Net and Java apps use basicHttpBinding.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netnamedpipebinding.aspx

Comment: The question states that this will be on the same machine.